# Run a script when Hibernate shuts down

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am using Hibernate to manage a test suite, and I need to run a custom script on shutdown.  I have found the property:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files
```

to run a script on startup, but I cannot find documentation for a similar property for shutdown.

More specifically, my import script is creating custom tables (which cannot be created through annotations for reasons I cannot change), and I need those custom tables to be dropped after the tests run.  I am using

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

which is destroying other tables created by the tests, but not the tables created in the import script.

Other technologies being used are Spring, JUnit, Postgres, and Maven, in case anyone has a hack involving those I could use to accomplish the same goal.

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking for a way to have Hibernate run a script to delete some tables after a test suite finishes running.

Comment: You're not clear on what you are really after. You mention "shutdown script" and "test suite" in one breath. So what then? You want to add a shutdown script for the application and test that, or do you want to run a script when the test suite has done all its tests?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification.  I want Hibernate to run a cleanup script when the test suite finishes all its tests, which I believe is the last thing you mentioned.  I will edit my initial post for more clarity.

Comment: So why are you then looking at hibernate, and not a shutdown method for whatever technology you are using to manage your test suite? I'm sure it is either JUnit or TestNG and both can do what you want.

Comment: The initial database setup and most of the database teardown are already being handled by the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop property, so I thought that Hibernate would have a similar mechanism for what I want.

I am using a maven command to run the test suite, so maybe I can find a way to have maven run a script as part of its cleanup routine.

Comment: why not specify a destroy script inside the <jdbc:intialize-database> tag?

Comment: I don't recognize that tag, and don't think we are using it anywhere.  Would that be something I can add to the Hibernate xml configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it via hbm2ddl. However, you can wire your DataSource into your test suite and then drop the tables directly via the data source. If you go this route you may find it cleaner to also do the creates the same way instead of using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`. Something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"spring-dao-test.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ExampleDaoTest extends extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ExampleDaoTest.class);

    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @BeforeMethod
    private void createExtraTables() {
        try {
            log.info("Creating table extra_table");
            dataSource.getConnection().createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE extra_table ( id number(4) not null )");
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            log.error("Unable to create table extra_table", se);
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    private void dropExtraTables() {
        try {
            log.info("Dropping table extra_table");
            dataSource.getConnection().createStatement().execute("DROP TABLE extra_table");
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            log.error("Unable to drop table extra_table", se);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeStuff() {

    }
}
```